# Word Frequency counter not counting past 1 per user input

Tags: python

I am very new to python and new to this website as well so if this question isn't worded well I apologize. Basically, the program I am trying to create is one that takes user inputs, counts the words in the inputs, and then also counts the occurrences of a specific list of common words. My problem is that when using a test case that has more than one occurrence of a word in my list, the counter does not count past 1. For example, if the user input is "A statement is a program instruction", it will only count the use of the word "a" one time. Below I have included my code, I also want to preface this with being my first attempt at using loops. I believe my problem lies within lines 31-32.

```
#step1
from re import X


words = ['the','be','to', 'of', 'and','a','in','that','have','i']
frequency = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
assert len(words) == len(frequency), "the length of words and frequency should be equal!"
total_frequency = 0
#step2
text = input("Enter some text:").lower()
#step3 repeated until == quit through step 7
while text != 'quit':
    #step4 split the input
    text_list = text.split(' ')
    #step5 update the frequency
    total_frequency = total_frequency+len(text_list)
    #step6 update the counter
    for idx, this_word in enumerate(words):
        # in the inner loop, you have to compare this_word with each element of text_list if they are the same, add on to frequency[idx]
        if this_word in text_list:
                frequency[idx]+=1 
        #step7: ask for another input
    text = input("Enter some text:").lower()
#step 8 format output
keys = '    '.join(words)
print(f'Total number of words:{total_frequency}')
print("{:^50}".format('Word frequency of top ten words'))
print('-'*50)
print(keys)
for idx, this_word in enumerate(words):
    print(f'{frequency[idx]:^{len(this_word)}}    ',end="")
print()

# END
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter some text:A statement is a program instruction
Enter some text:quit
Total number of words:6
         Word frequency of top ten words
--------------------------------------------------
the    be    to    of    and    a    in    that    have    i
 0     0     0     0      0     1    0      0       0      0
```

Comment: Python string comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: Right.  You are not iterating over the words in the input, you're iterating over your target words.  You would need to do something like `for word in text_list:` to look at all the words.

Comment: If you are allowed - use a dictionary instead of arrays.

Comment: or even better... a `Counter` https://realpython.com/python-counter/

Comment: `if  word in word_list` in this part (after this) you are adding 1 only not all the other occurences, so you need to use `frequency[idx]+=text_list.count(this_word)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your inner loop with this:

```
    for word in text_list:
        if word in words:
            frequency[words.index(word)] += 1
```

and you will get the results you want.  Note that it would be better to store your words and frequencies in a dict, so you could let Python do the searching, like this:

```
words = {'the':0,'be':0,'to':0, 'of':0, 'and':0,'a':0,'in':0,'that':0,'have':0,'i':0}
total_frequency = 0
#step2
text = input("Enter some text:").lower()
#step3 repeated until == quit through step 7
while text != 'quit':
    #step4 split the input
    text_list = text.split(' ')
    #step5 update the frequency
    total_frequency = total_frequency+len(text_list)
    #step6 update the counter
    for word in text_list:
        if word in words:
            words[word] += 1
    text = input("Enter some text:").lower()
#step 8 format output
keys = '    '.join(words.keys())
print(f'Total number of words:{total_frequency}')
print("{:^50}".format('Word frequency of top ten words'))
print('-'*50)
print(keys)
for word, cnt in words.items():
    print(f'{cnt:^{len(word)}}    ',end="")
print()
```

Answer (score -1):

if this_word in text_list returns true if 'this_word' is in there.  you need another loop.

```
for word in text_list:
     if this_word == word:
          frequency[idx]+=1
```

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: That's not any better.  Where are you going to put this loop?  Since you don't use "word" in the loop, you're just going to multiply all the counts by however many words are in the sentence.  You're on the wrong track here.